# Google tag manager - trigger by custom event with filter

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an event name "foo" which is sent to the GTM with an object of data.

```
  event: 'foo',
  eventData: {
   action: 'bar'
  }
```

[image]

I would like this trigger to fire when the EventData contains an action called "bar"

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `eventData` is an object, you can either use a Custom JavaScript variable to trigger your tag where you do the check from there, or you could also define a Data Layer variable for `eventData.action` and use that to trigger your tag. I'll leave it to you to play around and see what works. If you get stuck, post back here with what you've tried.